# Wrong number or types of arguments Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, reporting-services

I've been scratching my head over the resolution of this particular error I get from Oracle in my report viewer when I try to fetch data from an Oracle Stored Procedure onto my rdlc report.

Following is my C sharp code to supply the paramater values:

```
ReportParameter pInstrfinalStatus = new ReportParameter(repChequeStatus.ServerReport.GetParameters()[0].Name, InstrfinalStatus);
                            ReportParameter pFrmDt = new ReportParameter(repChequeStatus.ServerReport.GetParameters()[1].Name, FrmDt);
                            ReportParameter pToDt = new ReportParameter(repChequeStatus.ServerReport.GetParameters()[2].Name, ToDt);
                            ReportParameter pInstrType = new ReportParameter(repChequeStatus.ServerReport.GetParameters()[3].Name, InstrType);
                            ReportParameter pDepositLoc = new ReportParameter(repChequeStatus.ServerReport.GetParameters()[4].Name, DepositLoc);

                            ReportParameter LOGINID = new ReportParameter(repChequeStatus.ServerReport.GetParameters()[5].Name, LoginUser());
                            ReportParameter DT = new ReportParameter(repChequeStatus.ServerReport.GetParameters()[6].Name, CurrentDatetimeAppServer().ToString());
                            ReportParameter IPAdd = new ReportParameter(repChequeStatus.ServerReport.GetParameters()[7].Name, IPAddress());

                            //ReportParameter oUTCURS = new ReportParameter(repChequeStatus.ServerReport.GetParameters()[8].Name, OutCursor);
                            repChequeStatus.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { pInstrfinalStatus, pFrmDt, pToDt, pInstrType, pDepositLoc, LOGINID, DT, IPAdd });
                            //repChequeStatus.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { LOGINID, DT, IPAdd });
                            repChequeStatus.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

And following is my Stored procedure signature:

```
PROCEDURE BLAH
(
V_INSTR_FINAL_STATUS IN VARCHAR := null,
V_from_cheque_date IN DATE := null,
V_to_cheque_date IN DATE := null,
V_instrument_type IN VARCHAR := null,
V_DEPOSIT_LOCATION IN VARCHAR := null,
P_LOGINID  IN VARCHAR, 
P_DATETIMESTAMP IN TIMESTAMP,
P_IPAddress IN VARCHAR,
V_CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
);
```

What am I doing wrong or missing? I've tried supplying values to all the arguments, making the optional parameter as default null on oracle but nothing worked.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not an expert in c#, but the DT parameter definition end with "ToString()" whereas in the database it is defined as timestamp. Perhaps you need to convert "CurrentDatetimeAppServer()" result to timestamp somehow? And give it a try with hardcoded parameters values in c# just to make it sure it works at all

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @ekochergin. The parameters specified in c sharp code go to an SSRS report and from there they are provided to the Oracle Stored proc and the SSRS report accepts only string params from c  sharp and then converts it to the appropriate datatype as needed by the Oracle SP, so that is not a problem.

Comment: I assume Oracle is expecting a parameter placeholder for your out refcursor and you are not supplying one.  What database driver are you using in your SSRS report? - https://qa.social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa439139-e8a4-4fd0-8045-1b4700d40bd5/passing-parameters-to-oracle-stored-procedure?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: The code you've posted comments out `ReportParameter oUTCURS`. So that would be one explanation for the error.